# Scale with respect to height and width in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, scaling

I have 2 points (say `x1`, `y1` and `x2`, `y2`) in a div of width `w` and height `h`. I want to scale this points to a new div of height `h'` and width `w'`. My question is how do I calculate the new `x1'`, `y1'` and `x2'`, `y2'` for the new dimensions?

I tried by finding the scaling factor and divide by it, but it is not working :(
Can anybody help me?

Please find the fiddle here.

[Code for base image and canvas](http://jsfiddle.net/harikk09/0brpcrvs)

[Code for enlarged image to find co-ordinates](http://jsfiddle.net/harikk09/z85g0ex1)

Comment: You need to show your efforts..Fiddle will be helpful..

Comment: Fiddle really needed here :O

Comment: WIll update soon in fiddle